# What is wavelength of electric field generated in a wire?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-fields, electric-current, conductors

I read link given below:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_electricity

Above link says

> _The speed at which energy or signals travel down a cable is actually the speed of the electromagnetic wave, not the movement of
>   electrons. Electromagnetic wave propagation is fast and depends on the dielectric constant of the material. In a vacuum the wave travels at the speed of light and almost that fast in air.

and

> Since the velocity of propagation is very
>   high — about 300,000 kilometers per
>   second — the wave of an alternating or
>   oscillating current, even of high frequency,
>   is of considerable length. At 60 cycles per
>   second, the wavelength is 5,000 kilometers,
>   and even at 100,000 hertz, the wavelength
>   is 3 kilometers. This is a very large distance
>   compared to those typically used in field
>   measurement and application._

It gives wavelength of EM wave in wire.
**How did they find it?**

**Edit** : After reading comments

Also, why do you all say, it has nothing like that. That there is no such wavelength. Is Wikipedia wrong here then?

**Edit 2** : I got that what wiki said was something different. They simply used $v = \lambda \nu$

Now, I wonder that electric field is caused by virtual photons. What is their frequency and wavelength in wire?

Comment: The carriers are rather slow: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drift_velocity

Comment: Current has no velocity like this, it's only the number of carriers per unit time (I=dQ/dt).

Comment: Yes, if the cables were empty and you would have to fill them up with electrons. But they are already full of electrons, and applying an electric field, all free electrons start to move. It's like the water tap at home, you don't have to wait for the water to come all way from a water reservoir, it's already in the water pipe.

Comment: And you are only interested in how many liters you can get out of the water tap per minute. The speed of water isn't really important.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_electricity

Please refer above link

Comment: Re your last edit, when you connect the battery a signal that is basically a step function propagates along the wire at around $0.1c$ to $c$ depending on the type of wire. A step signal isn't a plane wave and doesn't have a frequency or wavelength.

Comment: @John Rennie : What does "Re your last edit mean".

Comment: @AnubhavGoel: on  Nov 27 '15 at 8:33 you edited your question and added a lot of new text. When I say *Re your last edit* I mean my comment specifically addresses the changes you made in that edit.

Comment: You have to read the Wikipedia quote more carefully. It's saying they assign wavelength to the *sinusoidal AC current* of 60 Hz, not to any "electromagnetic wave". This wavelength is not the wavelength of any actual oscillation.

Comment: Thank you John Rennie and ACuriousMind. My doubt is now cleared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first connect the source, there is a very brief transient during which the steady-state DC solution is set up. The speed of the *signal*, i.e. the electromagnetic wave front that carries the information along the wire, is a bit less than the speed of light because of transmission line effects. Figuring out exactly how long the transient lasts would require a simulation that accounts for the distributed capacitance, distributed inductance, resistivity, and shape of the wire, not to mention the properties of the battery itself, but you can still make a rough estimate of the time constant as being the size of the system divided by the speed of light. For a small thing sitting on a table we're talking a nanosecond or so, so the transient will have a spread of frequencies roughly in the GHz range. It won't have a single well-defined frequency in general.

Once the transient is finished, you're now in a DC steady-state condition, and the frequency is 0 while the wavelength is infinite.